# Which of these full houses wins?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, poker

In Texas Holdem:

Player one has: 1, 5
Player two has: 9, 9

The community cards are: 1, 5, 5, 9, 6

Both players have a full house.  Which player wins?

Comment: Hi Armando, welcome to the site! You may want to take the [tour].

Comment: Passersby: Please don't down vote good answers just because the question is a duplicate or otherwise closed.

Answer (score 0):

The player with the [9, 9] hand beats the player with the [1, 5] hand because a 9-9-9-5-5 full house beats a 5-5-5-1-1 full house (the higher value of the triple wins).  See https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/53389/9999 for a full explanation.